# Android ListView garbled view

Tags: android, android-listview

I created a simple ListView example and when I scroll, the view gets all garbled up. It keeps the fisrt page of items and simply displays the other items on top. It does the same thing on two different devices and on the emulator.

Here is my layout:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is my activity:

```
public class ListViewExampleActivity extends Activity
{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(layout.list_ex_view1);
    String[] values = new String[]{"Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2", "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile"};
    ListView listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));
}
```

}

You can see what it looks like here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBqUd.png

Comment: I also tried a ListActivity with the same results

Comment: Have your tried this on an actual device? It could be your emulator. It seems like a rendering problem more than a code problem.

Comment: yes, i have tried two physical devices, one running 3.2.1 and another one running 4.0.4 with the same results

Comment: That's really odd. I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. You might try making a new project, rewriting your test code (with minimal copy/paste to avoid taking the error with you) and seeing if you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I have a common theme that i assign to all my applications in the manifest with android:theme="@style/myTheme". It seems the problem is assigning @null to the android:windowBackground property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="myTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```